# How can I automatically populate rows in Google Sheets with ArrayFormula and combine it with data validation?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have two dropdowns, and dropdown B is dependent on dropdown A.

For example, column X is "fruit", "vegetables", "protein". If you choose "fruit" in column X, then column Y will give you only fruit as options (apple, banana, grapes). If you choose "protein" in column X, then column Y will show you "chicken", "beef", "pork". The dropdowns in column Y would change based on column X.

To do this, I figured out I can use a query formula, or I can use a Filter formula (with transpose): =transpose(FILTER(Dropdowns!A:A,Dropdowns!$B:B=X2)). X2 is where the "fruit", "vegetables", "protein" drop down would be. Then I can make the dropdowns in Y based on what is transposed.

I'd like to make sure that this transpose formula appears in every new row that is created.

I tried doing it with an ArrayFormula, but it is not working. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula that uses REDUCE to stack your function through all the rows:

```
=IFNA(REDUCE("Header",X2:X,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="",a,VSTACK(a,
transpose(FILTER(Dropdowns!A:A,Dropdowns!$B:B=x)))))))
```

Use it in row 1 of your helper column